# Fragment options menu - create multiple instances in the fragment stack

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-optionsmenu

I have an activity, A, and two fragments, B and C.

In both fragments B and C, I call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in the `onCreate()` method.

Additionally, for each I use the following methods:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // Doesn't help much...
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_act_detail, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_favorite_act) {
        Log.d(TAG, title);
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_visit_site_act) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

So each instance of the fragments B and C has a title and url. However, when I add multiple, different instances of B and C to the fragment stack, when I trigger the `action_favorite_act` option menu item, it logs the first instance's title.

This is the code I use to add an instance of B or C to the fragment stack:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = ActDetailFragment.newInstance(id);
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.flContent, fragment, id)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

The id in this case is the same as the url field belonging to each instance.

Example behavior:

- I add an instance of B to the fragment stack with title = "hello" and url = "test.com"
- I trigger the `action_favorite_act` menu item and it logs `hello`
- I add an instance of C to the fragment stack with title = "world" and url = "site.com"
- I trigger the `action_favorite_act` menu item and it logs `world`
- I add another instance of B to the fragment stack with title = "goodbye" and url = "another.com"
- I trigger the `action_favorite_act` menu item and it logs `hello` instead of `goodbye`!

No matter how many instances of B or C I add, the menu item seems to trace back to the first instance. So `hello` and `world` get logged instead of the titles of the instances of B and C that are at the top of the stack. How can I get the menu item at the top of the stack to respond to an action?

Comment: Since you're using `addToBackStack()`, can you confirm that after adding e.g. B, C, B, C, B, C, B, C you can press the back button and see multiple instances of the same fragment? I'm curious if `add()` is not actually adding the fragment because another fragment with that id is already added.

Comment: @BenP. Yes, when I press the back button, I do go back to each fragment that was added to the back stack.

Comment: What happens when you don't call menu.clear(), does it show the menu for each copy of the Fragment?

Comment: @lionscribe Removing menu.clear() only shows one menu - the first menu! So this is consistent with what Ben.P replicated in his answer below.

Comment: Try returning `false` to `onOptionsItemSelected` when `id = action_favorite_act`. Does the Log get printed for each title?

Comment: @lionscribe Oooh ~ as you said, when returning false there, the log does get printed for each title. But then I need each responding fragment to determine whether or not it's the current fragment / topmost fragment right?

Comment: Yes. But it is not simple. Google it and you will see. The better way would be, if possible, to use replace instead of add. This will require you to correctly deal with saving the state of the Fragment, (as it will be recreated when popped from stack), which you should anyways be doing.

Comment: @lionscribe I see. I was trying out getUserVisibleHint(), isVisible(), isAdded(), isDetached(), isRemoving(), just now and all fragments in the stack were still responding... Using replace would be difficult since some of the fragments contain really large lists with lots of entries - and replacing the fragments and recreating them would be expensive and time consuming.

Comment: You actually should be saving it all in the bundle when onSaveInstanceState is called. You should be handling it, otherwise when screen is rotated, or app is killed in background, your Fragments will have to be recreated from scratch, with scroll positions and selections lost. As I have commented multiple times on this site, you have to make sure not to recreate Fragments in Activity, when a bundle is passed to onCreate, as the OS will recreate them, and try to restore their state.

Comment: Another option is to hold the big data in the Activity class (or in a Singleton class), so that it is not lost when Fragment is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small app to try to duplicate your problem, and I could. By a stroke of luck, I used a transparent background for my fragments, which was helpful because it meant I got to see that all of my fragments were alive at once:

[image]

Like you, I noticed that I was always logging the same message (from the first fragment) when I selected the options menu item.

The root of the problem appears to be that every instance of your fragment class uses the same `R.id` constant for its menu items. So you have e.g. three instances of Fragment B in your activity, but all three *could* handle a click on `R.id.action_favorite_act`. Presumably the Activity simply iterates over its fragments and passes the menu event to each until someone handles it, and so the first one always wins.

You could solve this by using `replace()` instead of `add()`, so that there was only ever one instance of a given fragment class alive and attached at any one time.

If that doesn't meet your requirements, I believe you'll have to use dynamically generated ids for your menu items, so that each fragment has its own item ids.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed response and for verifying the behavior! I would like to avoid using `replace()` since it would cause my fragments to reload when I pressed the back button. I will look into dynamically generated menu ids.

Comment: @WayWay Dynamically setting the menu item id, will probably cause that you will have duplicate entries in your menu. If you call menu.clear(), then you will only have the menu ids of the last added menu, so you will still have issue.

Comment: @WayWay another possible solution would be to store a reference to the "current" fragment in your activity somehow (probably by `id` or `tag`) and then in `onOptionsItemSelected()` check to see if you're the current fragment and return false if not.

Comment: @Ben P. Not easy, for app does not control when user hits back key, and pops Fragment from stack. It's doable, but complicated and not foolproof.